# AVL Delete operation in SML

Tags: sml, avl-tree

I am implementing an AVL tree in ML and I am having a hard time implementing the delete operation.

```
datatype 'a AVLTree = Nil | Br of ((int*('a))*('a AVLTree)*('a AVLTree));
datatype Balance = RR | LR | LL | RL;
exception NotFound;
exception NullValue;
```

This what I got so far:

```
fun remove(Nil, _)            = Nil
  | remove ((Br((i,vi), t_l, t_r)), j) = 
      case Int.compare(i,j) of 
           LESS    =>  remove(t_l,j)
         | GREATER =>  remove(t_r,j)
         | EQUAL   => (case (t_l, t_r) of
                         (Nil , _) => t_r
                        |(_,  Nil) => t_l
                        |  _       => if getHeight t_l <= getHeight t_r 
                                      then let val mk = getMinKey t_r
                                                 val mv = get(t_r,mk) 
                                           in(Br((mk,mv), t_l,(remove(t_r,mk))))
                                           end
                                      else let val mk = getMaxKey t_l
                                               val mv = get(t_l,mk)
                                  in (Br((mk,mv), (remove(t_l, mk)), t_r))end);
```

My idea was to find the node which I want to delete, and it's successor, and then switch between them and deleting the leaf where the successor was so that I won't need to balance the tree.

I implemented it this way because I was having a hard time knowing when to use the rotations in the delete operation.

This operation does indeed delete the node I want but it doesn't keep the property of an AVL tree.

Would be happy to get some help here.

Comment: You can't avoid rotations, but the procedure is fairly well documented both in the literature and online.

Answer (score 0):

> My idea was to find the node which I want to delete, and it's successor, and then switch between them and deleting the leaf where the successor was so that I won't need to balance the tree.

When you delete an element, you may have to re-balance the tree. You can't avoid that, since if trees could effortlessly be balanced after insertion or deletion, there would be no need for any additional mechanism for re-balancing. Here are some hints:

- In the cases of `LESS` and `GREATER`, you discard the entire tree! There is a simple fix; you simply want to remember to re-construct the tree:

  ```
  datatype 'a AVLTree = Nil | Br of (int * 'a) * 'a AVLTree * 'a AVLTree

  fun remove (Nil, _) = Nil
    | remove (Br ((i, vi), tLeft, tRight), j) =
      case Int.compare (i, j) of
           LESS    => let val tRight' = remove (tRight, j)
                          val newTree = Br ((i, vi), tLeft, tRight')
                      in newTree end
         | GREATER => (* ... same, but opposite sides ... *)
         | EQUAL   => (* ... *)
  ```
- In the cases of `LESS` and `GREATER` you forget to re-balance the tree after removing an element, if necessary. After deletion you can check if the height differs too much and then perform the appropriate rotation. Adding this check to the `LESS` path might look like:

  ```
  fun remove (Nil, _) = Nil
    | remove (Br ((i, vi), tLeft, tRight), j) =
      case Int.compare (i, j) of
           LESS    => let val tRight' = remove (tRight, j)
                          val newTree = Br ((i, vi), tLeft, tRight')
                      in if height newTree = height tRight' + 2 
                         then (* ... re-balance one way ... *)
                         else newTree
                      end
         | GREATER => (* ... same, but opposite sides; re-balance other way... *)
         | EQUAL   => (* ... *)
  ```
- The `EQUAL` case appears to be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
But how do I literally rebalance (if needed) all the way until the root after I deleted the node?
I am having a hard time to see where all those rebalancings take place. I see only one rebalance in the code...

Comment: @Eden: The rebalance is recursive. Upon every return from a recursive call to `remove`, we ask if the difference in height of the sub-trees is too big (`if height newTree = ...`). If that's the case, `newTree` needs a rotation to whatever side is the smallest. Then that recursive call returns to *its* parent which again makes this assessment and rotates if necessary.